Forcing drain pipe into p trap in an angle

Hi everyone, i was trying to replace my vanity top, and after separating the faucet out, i noticed that it actually does not align with the drainage pipe. And my contractor had just forced them into each other.
Now i have 0 plumbing knowledge, and am kinda scared to add the extension pipes myself, but ofc, dont really want to spend $500 on a plumber either.
So i was just wondering, if it would be okay to force things back together with my new faucet as well, the drainage pipe is not stuck in position, it can move quite a bit, and the faucet drain would need to meet it mid way. Just wondering if it would cause a huge issue with the drain pipe and would leak inside the wall somewhere.
i was told that the p trap could be adjusted, but it seems like ours is glued in that angle, wouldnt budge even after i loosenedthe knob(?)

Your contractor does not know anything about plumbing either! This is a hack job built upon a hack job. Unfortunately it needs to be ripped out and redone properly.

The part of the P trap that can be adjusted I've marked with an arrow:

Loosening this ring, the trap can be rotated so that the pipe lines up with the drain pipe attached to the sink.
What is currently attached to your sink, however, and the threaded coupler at the top of your P trap won't attach to each other. The drain pipe looks... interesting.

Thanks for your reply,  but it seems like its somehow glued together. I cant seem to adjust the angle even after i loosened the part

If you loosen the ring completely, can you separate the two pieces? It may be just very snug, as the whole purpose of the threaded flange and ring is to avoid the need for gluing it. If they did glue it, there will be no option besides cutting the pipe at some location.

Yeah it doesnt seem to budge after i remove the ring fully :(
